# Stretching input group without input field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Might be a misuse of Bootstrap's input group component, but should be achievable.

This is what I have:

[image]

And here's how I'd like to have it:

[image]

The code that needs fixing:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">foo</span>
      <span class="input-group-text">bar</span>
      <span class="input-group-text">This should stretch.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">baz</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">qux</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

div.cont {
  border-left: 1px dotted gray;
  border-right: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/37o25zay/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boostrap class `flex-grow-1` to allow the element to grow and fill the remaining space (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink)

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

div.cont {
  border-left: 1px dotted gray;
  border-right: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="cont">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend flex-grow-1"> <!-- here -->
      <span class="input-group-text">foo</span>
      <span class="input-group-text">bar</span>
      <span class="input-group-text flex-grow-1">This should stretch.</span> <!-- here -->
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">baz</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">qux</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```